# Is it possible to prepend the generated styled-component classes with a custom class?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, styled-components, classname

Is it possible in the output of styled-components for a project to prepend all the classes with a fixed string?

e.g.

```
class="sc-fznyAO"
```

Would become

```
class="myProjectOne-sc-fznyAO"
```

I have several compiled projects running on the same page, each of which is a react app in a dedicated .js file. It would really help the readability and specificity to prepend all the random generated hashes  with the project it was generated in.

So far tried using `import styled from 'styled-components/macro';` to import styled-components. This gives some more controll and specificity. But I'm not really looking for controll every single element. These can all stay random hashes, I just want to prepend every single class with the same string for each project.
I think this should be possible somewhere in the webpack configuration, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example which will give you a prepended class name

```
export const Example = styled("div").withConfig({ displayName: "myProjectOne" })(
  css`
    width: 100%;
  `
);
```

Comment: displayName does seem to be the right direction, do you know if there is a way to set the dispalyName for all the styled components in one single go in stead of for each individual styled component? Like in the webpack config?